# Automatically change the color of a single character

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

I wasn't able to find an answer for my specific topic.
But I've found a similiar topic, but I'm not able to adapt it to my needs.

I have found the following solution here (copy past from Alex Ivanov)

...
The main code can be like this

```
/**
 * @file Painting specific characters in cells
 * {@link https://support.google.com/docs/thread/11987044}
 */
/**
 * Runs the snippet
 */
function run() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var char = '|';
  var color = 'red';
  paintingSpecificCharacters_(range, char, color);
}
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Range} range
 * @param {string} char
 * @param {string} color
 */
function paintingSpecificCharacters_(range, char, color) {
  var textStyleBuilder = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle();
  textStyleBuilder.setForegroundColor(color);
  var textStyle = textStyleBuilder.build();
  var length = char.length;
  var richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(richTextValue) {
      var value = richTextValue.getText();
      var richTextBuilder = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue();
      richTextBuilder.setText(value);
      var indexOf = value.indexOf(char);
      while (indexOf > -1) {
        richTextBuilder.setTextStyle(indexOf, indexOf + length, textStyle);
        indexOf = value.indexOf(char, indexOf + length);
      }
      return richTextBuilder.build();
    });
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

In this approach you have to select a range before execute run. Lets imagine we need to color a word "hello" just set it as

```
function run() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var char = 'hello';
  var color = 'red';
  paintingSpecificCharacters_(range, char, color);
}
```

Check it and ask me more!
...?

Coming now to my request.
Do you know how to adapt the code in case I have a predefined range within my code?
For example:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName.getRange("B2:B100")
```

I would like that it works when I execute the script just by clicking on the "run" button.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards
Max

Comment: I use rich text. There's an example in [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70161284/7215091)

Comment: One comment I have on your code is if there are any other rich text setting in the line of text they will be lost.  `var value = richTextValue.getText();` returns a text string but no prevous rich text settings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use your showing script by declaring the range like `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName.getRange("B2:B100")`.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this case, please modify `run()` as follows.

#### From:

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
```

#### To:

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2:B100");
```

Or, if you want to use the active sheet, please modify it as follows.

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:B100");
```

- Please modify `Sheet1` of `getSheetByName("Sheet1")` to your actual sheet name.
- About `I would like that it works when I execute the script just by clicking on the "run" button.`, in this case, when you assign the function `run` to a button on Spreadsheet, you can run the script by clicking the button.

#### Note:

- In your current script, the richtext of the original cell value is reset. If you want to keep the original richtext in the cell, how about modifying `paintingSpecificCharacters_` as follows? In this modification, the richtext of the original cell value is kept.

  ```
    function paintingSpecificCharacters_(range, char, color) {
      const format = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor(color).build();
      const v = range.getRichTextValues().map(r =>
        r.map(c => {
          const text = c.getText();
          const idx = text.indexOf(char);
          if (idx != -1) {
            return c.copy().setTextStyle(idx, idx + char.length, format).build();
          }
          return c;
        })
      );
      range.setRichTextValues(v);
    }
  ```